# Convert rows into comma separated string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df2 = DataFrame({'a' : ['one', 'one', 'two','two', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'six'], 
                 'b' : ['x', 'y', 'z', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x']})
```

I need to group it using column `'a'`.

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['a'])
```

Next, I want to convert the column `'b'` into comma-separated strings, the resulting table should look like this:

```
a       b
---------------

one     j, k, l

two     m, n, o

three   p, q
```

Does anyone know how to do it without leaving pandas? It seems simple, but can't find a way to do it inside pandas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

edited from @DSM comment

```
In [12]: df2.groupby('a')['b'].apply(','.join)
Out[12]: 
a
one      x,y,x
six          x
three        x
two      z,y,y
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Comment: I get the same result with just the function `lambda x: ", ".join(x)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff and mtadd!

Comment: Well, if we really want to condense, there's no need for the `lambda`: we can `.apply(','.join)` directly.